# Use data from JSON response in python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, response

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD")
print(response.json())
```

gets me

```
{"rates":{"CAD":1.327455236,"HKD":7.8246518358,"ISK":123.259178875,"PHP":50.8545849159,"DKK":6.7577319588,"HUF":302.3060227889,"CZK":23.0719840839,"GBP":0.7775366251,"RON":4.3173268222,"SEK":9.6097847712,"IDR":14084.997287032,"INR":71.6865617652,"BRL":4.188189546,"RUB":63.6969614759,"HRK":6.7249954784,"JPY":108.545849159,"THB":30.1953336951,"CHF":0.994212335,"EUR":0.9043226623,"MYR":4.1710074154,"BGN":1.768674263,"TRY":5.7079942123,"CNY":7.0387050099,"NOK":9.1411647676,"NZD":1.5586905408,"ZAR":14.7149574968,"USD":1.0,"MXN":19.3951890034,"SGD":1.3629951167,"AUD":1.4728703201,"ILS":3.4664496292,"KRW":1178.395731597,"PLN":3.8865075059},"base":"USD","date":"2019-11-22"}
```

How do I assign the EUR (for example) int to a variable? I've tried a few different ways and can't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd do

```
eur = response.json()['rates']['EUR']
```

You address JSON objects like dictionaries since python does decode them into lists and dictionaries accordingly.

Comment: You don't address JSON objects (which are all strings) at all; you use the *Python* object that `response.json()` returns.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that it gets decoded into lists and dictionaries